# Locust and Websockets

Tags: python, websocket, aiohttp, locust

I want to make a simple Locust script for a WebSocket call preferably using aiohttp.
Request URL:

```
wss://someurl/api/task/ws
```

Request Method:

```
GET
```

Staus code:

```
101 Switching Protocols
```

Using "Class" and "task" as Locust spesifics, how could that script look like using aiohttp?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the (somewhat incorrectly named) `SocketIOUser` in locust-plugins https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/socketio_ex.py

aiohttp uses async which is a little complicated to combine with gevent/greenlets which Locust Users are based on.